# Ошибка: Warning: mcrypt_decrypt(): The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize

Tags: php

Выдает ошибку:

> Warning: mcrypt_decrypt(): The IV parameter must be as long as the
>   blocksize in ......../libraries/fof/encrypt/aes.php on line 151

В районе 151 строки (150-160 строки) следующий код:

```
// Decrypt the data
    $plainText = mcrypt_decrypt($this->_cipherType, $key, $stringToDecrypt, $this->_cipherMode, $iv);

    return $plainText;
}

/**
 * Is AES encryption supported by this PHP installation?
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что где поправить?

Comment: Покажите как получаете `$iv`. Текст ошибки явно говорит что не так